# Foreach loop data passed to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, I'm going to try to explain this the best I can.

I have a product filter on my website that is built using php foreach to create the filter headers and options from a data base. The code it generates is below.

```
<div class="card mb-2 card-body alert-filters">
<h4>Product Filter</h4>
<div class="row">
  <div 
     class="col-md-3">
     <h5>Price</h5>
     <input type="hidden" id="hidden_minimum_price" value="0"> <input 
        type="hidden" id="hidden_maximum_price" value="50">
     <p id="price_show">£0 - £50</p>
     <div 
        id="price_range" class="ui-slider ui-corner-all ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget- 
        content">
        <div class="ui-slider-range ui-corner-all ui-widget-header" style="left: 0%; width: 
           100%;"></div>
        <span tabindex="0" class="ui-slider-handle ui-corner-all ui-state-default" 
           style="left: 0%;"></span><span tabindex="0" class="ui-slider-handle ui-corner-all ui- 
state- default" style="left: 100%;"></span>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
     <h5>Material</h5>
     <div 
        style="height: 180px; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden;">
        <div class="list-group-item 
           checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" class="common_selector brand1" value="3"> 
Metal</label> 
        </div>
        <div class="list-group-item checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" 
class="common_selector 
           brand1" value="1"> PLA</label></div>
        <div class="list-group-item checkbox"><label><input 
           type="checkbox" class="common_selector brand1" value="4"> Resin</label></div>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div 
     class="col-md-3">
     <h5>Base</h5>
     <div style="height: 180px; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden;">
        <div class="list-group-item checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" 
class="common_selector 
           brand2" value="2"> Included</label></div>
     </div>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" name="cPath" id="cPath" 
     value="15_13_14">
</div>
```

The category id is added to the class 'brand'. This is then passed to the jquery below -

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    filter_data();

    function filter_data()
    {
        $('.filter_data').html('<div id="loading" style="" ></div>');
        var action = 'fetch_data';
        var minimum_price = $('#hidden_minimum_price').val();
        var maximum_price = $('#hidden_maximum_price').val();
        var cPath = $("#cPath").val();
        var brand = get_filter('brand');
        $.ajax({
            url:"ext/filter/fetch_data.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{action:action, minimum_price:minimum_price, maximum_price:maximum_price, 
    brand:brand, cPath: cPath},
            success:function(data){
                $("#product_list").html(data);
            }
        });
    }

    function get_filter(class_name)
    {
        var filter = [];
        $('.'+class_name+':checked').each(function(){
            filter.push($(this).val());
        });
        return filter;
    }

    $('.common_selector').click(function(){
        filter_data();
    });

    $('#price_range').slider({
        range:true,
        min:0,
        max:50,
        values:[0, 50],
        step:1,
        stop:function(event, ui)
        {
            $('#price_show').html('£' + ui.values[0] + ' - ' + '£' + ui.values[1]);
            $('#hidden_minimum_price').val(ui.values[0]);
            $('#hidden_maximum_price').val(ui.values[1]);
            filter_data();
        }
    });

});
```

This works fine if I do not add the category ID as it just uses the 'brand'.

What I am wanting to do is have a var for 'brand1', 'brand2' etc depending on how many categories there are or a way to group them together and I can split them out on the proceeding page.

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding you, you need a way of cycling through different brands without knowing ahead of time what those brands are. You're using the brand 'name' as a class. Instead you can set it as a separate attribute (not a classname), so as to make it easier to segregate. Here I used `data-brand` to store the brand name and a simple loop to gather the checked category ids after clicking.

Update: Not sure if you need the category id values or the brand names, so this filter function returns both. Look at the console.log I put in there.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  filter_data();

  function filter_data() {
    $('.filter_data').html('<div id="loading" style="" ></div>');
    var action = 'fetch_data';
    var minimum_price = $('#hidden_minimum_price').val();
    var maximum_price = $('#hidden_maximum_price').val();
    var cPath = $("#cPath").val();
    var filter = get_filter('brand');
    // to get the brand names: filter.brand
    // or if you wan tthe category values: filter.values
    $.ajax({
      url: "ext/filter/fetch_data.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: {
        action: action,
        minimum_price: minimum_price,
        maximum_price: maximum_price,
        brand: filter.brand,
        cPath: cPath
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $("#product_list").html(data);
      }
    });
  }


  // filters by dataset and value
  function get_filter(what) {
    let filter = {
      [what]: [],
      values: []
    };
    $('.common_selector:checked').each(function() {
      let b = $(this).data(what)
      if (!filter[what].includes(b)) filter[what].push(b)
      filter.values.push($(this).val())
    })
    console.log('filter', filter)
    return filter;
  }

  $('.common_selector').click(function() {
    filter_data();
  });

  /*$('#price_range').slider({
        range:true,
        min:0,
        max:50,
        values:[0, 50],
        step:1,
        stop:function(event, ui)
        {
            $('#price_show').html('£' + ui.values[0] + ' - ' + '£' + ui.values[1]);
            $('#hidden_minimum_price').val(ui.values[0]);
            $('#hidden_maximum_price').val(ui.values[1]);
            filter_data();
        }
    });*/

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card mb-2 card-body alert-filters">
  <h4>Product Filter</h4>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <h5>Price</h5>
      <input type="hidden" id="hidden_minimum_price" value="0"> <input type="hidden" id="hidden_maximum_price" value="50">
      <p id="price_show">£0 - £50</p>
      <div id="price_range" class="ui-slider ui-corner-all ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget- 
        content">
        <div class="ui-slider-range ui-corner-all ui-widget-header" style="left: 0%; width: 
           100%;"></div>
        <span tabindex="0" class="ui-slider-handle ui-corner-all ui-state-default" style="left: 0%;"></span><span tabindex="0" class="ui-slider-handle ui-corner-all ui- 
state- default" style="left: 100%;"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <h5>Material</h5>
      <div style="overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden;">
        <div class="list-group-item 
           checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" class="common_selector" data-brand="brand1" value="3"> 
Metal</label>
        </div>
        <div class="list-group-item checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" 
class="common_selector" data-brand="brand1" value="1"> PLA</label></div>
        <div class="list-group-item checkbox"><label><input 
           type="checkbox" class="common_selector" data-brand="brand1" value="4"> Resin</label></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <h5>Base</h5>
      <div style="overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden;">
        <div class="list-group-item checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" 
class="common_selector" data-brand="brand2" value="2"> Included</label></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="cPath" id="cPath" value="15_13_14">
  </div>
```

Comment: Yes that's pretty much what I'm aiming for. How would your code fit into mine though?

Comment: Check out the revised answer and see if that helps.

Comment: Not quite doing what I want but getting there. I'm hoping to get an array that show value 1 & 3 under brand1 and value 2 under brand2. I'm sure I can work it out from here though